# Stored procedure not working in MVC (Umbraco) when passing parameters

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, umbraco

I have a SQL Server stored procedure that works fine in SQL Server Management Studio. I am trying to execute that stored procedure in C#. How do I set up the parameters in C#?

Here is what the stored procedure execute looks like in Management Studio:

```
EXEC [dbo].[NextNum] @site='00'
```

It returns a value.

Here is my C# code I am trying to use:

```
string ArtifactIDPrefix = dto.DbRecord.SiteID;
var sqlParams = new {siteID = ArtifactIDPrefix };
var results = db.Query<Artifact>("NextNum @site", sqlParams);
```

When I run the code, I get this error:

> Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Database.d__74}

and

> SELECT [NewtblArtifact].[ArtifactID], [NewtblArtifact].[SiteID], FROM [NewtblArtifact] NextNum @0
>
> SELECT [NewtblArtifact].[ArtifactID], [NewtblArtifact].[CatalogDate] FROM [NewtblArtifact] NextNum @0 -> @0 [String] = "00"

I have tried a few other version of the parameters with no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are using Entity where the project should have a mapping between the c# classes and the database.  Do other queries work (not including the Stored Procedure)?

Comment: yes they do. This is the only Query that is not working.

Comment: Does this help : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/designer/advanced/multiple-result-sets

Comment: Thanks, I looked through that previously and couldn't find a solution to what is going on.

Comment: It should be `var sqlParams = new { site = ArtifactIDPrefix };` (instead of siteID)

Comment: Davor, thanks for catching that. now I am getting this error - Incorrect syntax near '@0'.